# Extract dictionary object inside a Div with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following sample:

```
    [<div class="options__list">
    <a href="/link1">
    <div class="options__list__item" option-message="closed" data-option='{"id":1,"is_active":true,"name":"Fran","city":{"id":32,"name":"Paris","is_top":null,"url_key":"paris","main_area":{"id":null,"name":null,"url_key":null}}}'></div>
</a><a href="/link2">
    <div class="options__list__item" option-message="closed" data-option='{"id":2,"is_active":true,"name":"Fran2","city":{"id":32,"name":"Paris","is_top":null,"url_key":"paris","main_area":{"id":null,"name":null,"url_key":null}}}'></div>
</a>]
```

I would like to extract :

1. the href link
2. the dictionary "data-option".

What is the best way to do this? Moreover, let's say that I only wanted to extract specific keys from the "data-option" dictionary, how would I do that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be to iterate over the links, get the `href` attribute values, then find the inner option list items and use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to load the `data-option` value into the python dictionary:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <div class="options__list">
        <a href="/link1">
            <div class="options__list__item" option-message="closed" data-option='{"id":1,"is_active":true,"name":"Fran","city":{"id":32,"name":"Paris","is_top":null,"url_key":"paris","main_area":{"id":null,"name":null,"url_key":null}}}'></div>
        </a>
        <a href="/link2">
            <div class="options__list__item" option-message="closed" data-option='{"id":2,"is_active":true,"name":"Fran2","city":{"id":32,"name":"Paris","is_top":null,"url_key":"paris","main_area":{"id":null,"name":null,"url_key":null}}}'></div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for link in soup.select(".options__list > a"):
    href = link['href']
    data_option = json.loads(link.select_one("div.options__list__item")["data-option"])

    print(href, data_option['id'])
```

Prints (printing `href` values and option ids for demonstration purposes):

```
(u'/link1', 1)
(u'/link2', 2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For the data_option line, it gives me an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: @morfara could you show what code are you executing? Thanks.

Comment: I am executing the exact above code that you have written.

Comment: @morfara yeah, but do you have a different value of `data`?

Comment: Nope. I am passing the exact same code that you have written above to test that it works. The code works if I cross out the data_option line, but when I include it it gives the above TypeError.

Comment: @morfara interesting, works for me with no errors. Can you try upgrading `bs4`? Execute `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4`. Thanks.

Comment: What python are you using? I am using 2.7

Comment: This is how I made it work:     `data_option = json.loads(link.find('div', {'class': 'options__list__item'})["data-option"])`

Comment: @morfara you are definitely not using the latest bs4, cause it looks like select_one is not supported in your bs4 version