# Using BeautifulSoup to extract items from a dictionary

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How to i extract "loginError" and its value from the untis dict

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.untisUIVersion = 2;
        window.untisMomentLocale= "de";
        window.untis__webpack_public_path__ = "https://content.webuntis.com/WebUntis/static/2022.14.2/js/untis/";
        untis = {
            config: {"mode":"STANDARD","locale":"de-at","contextPath":"/WebUntis","licence":{"name":"HTBLA Weiz","name2":"A-8160, Dr.Karl-Widdmannstr. 40"},"mandantName":"htbla-weiz","mandant":16270,"customerNumber":70284,"imageServiceConfig":{"customLogo":true},"loginServiceConfig":{"ssoType":"none","samlProviderLabel":"","idpName":"","loginError":"Invalid user name and/or password","lastUserName":"","lastMandantName":"htbla-weiz"},
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: Try looking at [Extract dictionary object inside a Div using Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449310/extract-dictionary-object-inside-a-div-with-beautiful-soup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to work on this, but you will have to work on the transformation directly. How you would want the transformation process to work is solely depends on you.

This is how I will work on this.

I will first get the string data from the web or where-ever you get your data from.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find('script')
stringtext = results.get_text()
```

Then I will start to transform the text data into Json format (because is easy to work on). In my example, I split the string into array using `;` semicolon, then remove any leading and trailing whitespaces, replace more than 1 consecutive whitespaces into 1 whitespace, and load the rest as a Json object.

```
array = stringtext.split(';')
untis = array[3].strip()
untis = re.sub("\s\s+"," ", untis)
structjson = json.loads(untis[18:-6]+"}")
```

With the JSON object you can now look for what you need.

```
In[] : print(structjson["loginServiceConfig"]["loginError"])
Out[]: Invalid user name and/or password
```

This is just the logic behind working with `BeautifulSoup`. I do not think that you can extract the "loginError" as a key with `BeautifulSoup`. The only way to work with this is to extract it as a text and work on it directly in Python. You can better automate the logic by using regex search to identify the open curly and close curly braces indexes and extract those value. If you are working with large datasets, then you should not store the value in the list but just transforming the selected text on-fly or with Big Data framework like Apache Spark.